# FMX Grid with Checkbox not displaying property

Tags: delphi, grid, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I have a grid with a CheckColumn connected through livebindings with a query. When i open my query all my data is loaded into grid, but the checkbox do not show. If i click on the grid then the checkbox appears.

Picture when i open my query:

[image: Picture01]

When i click on the grid:

[image]

Comment: Please, report this issue then.

Comment: Grid and StringGrid have a lot of weird behaviors, if you cant stand this you could try with a 3rd party component like Oprheus (free)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that using `gridItens.Content.Repaint` Redraw the `checkboxes`, for now I'll keep it that way, but I'll take a look at this component @Alberto Miola!